# How To Set Display None of <footer> tag with Console?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide some fields on sites with javascript. For this, I **use the console** of the relevant **browser** and here I make that field **display = "none";** with ClassName or ID, but I made a few attempts to improve these things a little more.

In these experiments, I only found a field with `<footer>` tag, but it has neither ClassName nor ID.

`document.getElementsByClassName("footer")[0].style.display = "none";`

How can I make it invisible with js code? Thank you very much if you can get back to me. I am trying to learn something new.

Comment: `document.querySelector()` is the one you need to use for this! it can be used also for selecting **ids** using `#` or classes using `.` (basically inserting the CSS syntax for selectors) and much more like (`>`, `[space]`, `~`, `+`, and any other complex scenarios) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `document.querySelector()` function. This allows you to specify any valid CSS selector, meaning that in this case you can use the element's tag type to identify it.

Demo:

```js
document.querySelector("footer").style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div>Another div</div>
<footer>Hello</footer>
```

The code will remove the existing "Hello" message by hiding the footer element. All that's still on display is the "Another div".

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 1):

You can already create a class in CSS with style display: none; and later add or append that class on the footer,

```js
let element = document.querySelector(".footer");

 function hideFooter() {
  element.classList.add("hide");
 }
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
<!-- footer code -->
<p>This Is Footer </p>
</footer>

<button onClick="hideFooter()"> Hide Footer </button>
```